# ModX. AjaxSnippet не вызывает сниппет

Tags: ajax, modx, сниппет

Работаю в cms ModX. Установила пакет AjaxSnippet. Решила протестировать, написала сниппет JustTest со следующим содержимым:

```
return "test";
```

Вызываю его на странице сайта вот так:

```
[[AjaxSnippet?
    &snippet=`JustTest`
    &as_mode=`onclick`
    &as_trigger=`Нажми меня!`
]]
```

Реакции нет никакой, в логах тоже ничего не вижу. Что я делаю не так?

Comment: jQuery установлен? попробуйте вызовите некешируемым

Comment: @AntonTarasov jQuery не установлен. Если некешируемый - это восклицательный знак перед AjaxSnippet, то я его добавила, все то же самое